# Automatic rearrangement and regions

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, phpstorm

When JetBrains' IDE's [automatic rearrangement feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/rearranging-code-using-arrangement-rules.html#d479051e53) is used, it seems it ignores [regions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/) and move items between code regions. Is there any way to prevent moving items from a region to another on when rearranging?

Comment: There is possibility to use "sections" (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93452) which could be used to recognise regions ( at least the idea to do this automatically was mentioned in this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93452#comment=27-734077 ). Have you tried it? or maybe it will require every section to be declared explicitly?..

Comment: @LazyOne I dont get how that issue is related to this question. I need region-wide rearrangement, no code should go out from its region.

Comment: In my understanding: Sections are regions -- you have to define them otherwise IDE will apply those rearrangement rules for whole file. That's just a suggestion based on what I see in IDE and help pages -- I have not used it myself (no need as I prefer manual positioning (not ideal, but...)).